# specialised method nerver called in polymorph class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have several specialized method for same kind of behaviour in a code for geometric operations using polymorphism but only the parent class method is ever called.
This is the function always called in class Bound:

```
public override bool Intersect(SpatialData d)
{
    Type T = d.GetType();
    if (T == typeof(Vector)) return Intersect((Vector)d);
    if (T == typeof(Cell)) return Intersect((Cell)d);
    if (T == typeof(Bound)) return Intersect((Bound)d);
    if (T == typeof(Polygon)) return Intersect((Polygon)d);
    if (T == typeof(ConvexPolygon)) return Intersect((ConvexPolygon)d);
    if (T == typeof(Circle)) return Intersect((Circle)d);
    if (T == typeof(Edge)) return Intersect((Edge)d);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

All class above (vector, cell, bound...) inerit from abstract SpatialData class. 
All Intersect variants override abstract corresponding method in SpatialData.
Of course this code is ugly but if I dont do that this call the above methode instead of specialized one :

```
public List<T> Intersect(SpatialData bbox)
{
    /*...*/
    if (!Root.Intersect(bbox)) return result;
```

Where bbox is a Vector:SpatialData and Root a Node:Bound and Bound:SpatialData

So, how to make the Root.Intersect(bbox) call Bound.Intersect(Vector) instead of Bound.Intersect(SpatialData) ?

Hope I'm clear :s

Comment: Consider using `dynamic`.

Comment: Any class that inherits from another class is technically an instance of that parent class in addition to itself. This is why Intersect(SpatialData) is being called, because the most general interpretation of a class type is used. I wouldn't consider the code you have ugly, it does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: Where is that `Intersect` method defined?

Comment: The public List<T>Intersect(SaptialData bbox) method is defined in a non geometry class and is used to return all geometry of type T intersecting with bbox.
Like returning all vertices intersecting with a square.

Comment: "dynamic" works, thanks.